# Porque una app en Android solo funciona en modelos especificos de celular?

Tags: android, android-studio

Apenas he empezado a tener acceso a la aplicacion de mi trabajo, ya que me mencionan que tiene muchas fallas con layouts(Listviews) y  permisos de la aplicacion(Activar camara). Cuando lo probe con varios celulares me percate de algo.

**La aplicacion funciona, pero con solo modelos especificos de celular.**

La aplicación esta desarrollada desde la version Android 5.0, entonces mi primera conclusion es que las versiones superiores a este fallarian porque **X método** no es complatible con **X versión**,  pero no es asi.

Para poner un ejemplo:

> Tengo un *Moto e6i* con v8.0 y un *Redmi Note 9s* con v11 que no funcionan correctamente. Pero tambien tengo un *Moto e5* v8.0 y un *Moto e20* v11 en donde si funciona la aplicación en la mayoria de los casos.

Dicho esto, que podria ocasionar estos errores con la aplicación?, soy relativamente nuevo en Android Studio, lo he usado antes pero no a profundidad, me gustaria pudieran ayudarme en base a su experiencia cuales podrian ser las principales causas para que esto pase. Gracias.

Comment: Android es un entorno muy fragmentado. Cada fabricante publica actualizaciones y ajustes acorde a su hardware. Te corresponde probar en Android Studio usando los perfiles de diferentes dispositivos y leugo probar físicamente con diversos dispositivos para asegurar el funcionamiento.

Comment: ¡Gracias, lo tomare muy en cuenta!

Comment: Agrega el build.gradle de tu app y recuerda siempre revisar el LogCat. "en donde si funciona la aplicación en la mayoria de los casos.", en que casos no funciona? , revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: No me es permitido mencionar los casos especificos de los casos no funcionales, tan solo mencione un caso hipotetico como referencia para conocer posibles soluciones, de igual forma gracias por la recomendación!